# Cant match a particular pattern in regex using OR

Tags: python, regex

Here is my regex :

```
(M|D|MD|A|AM|AD|AMD)?=(0|1|-1|D|A|!D|!A|-D|-A|D\+A)?
```

It matches with

```
M=D 
M=A
M=1 
and so on
```

but it doesnt match with

```
M=D+A
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Regex goes from left to right and does not backtrack. And once an earlier part of an 'or' statement is satisfied, it does not look further. So you are capturing the shorter string and the regex never gets to the end of your 'or' statement where the longer string is. Changing your regex to

```
(M|D|MD|A|AM|AD|AMD)?=(D\+A|0|1|-1|D|A|!D|!A|-D|-A)?
```

will do the trick. In other words, always order your 'or' statements in a way that you first capture the longer strings and later capture the shorter ones.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/DVTC42/1)

Comment: Now i understood why my simple regex was not working

Answer (score 0):

You need a quantifier for the group as in:

```
(M|D|MD|A|AM|AD|AMD)?=((?:\+A|0|1|-1|D|A|!D|!A|-D|-A)+)
#                      ^^^                          ^^^
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/YLPrge/1/).

---

Depending on your actual needs, a simpler regex like `(\w+)=([-+!\w]+)` and a programmatical check afterwards might be easier to understand though.
See an example for the latter on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/YLPrge/3/) as well.

Comment: I didnt understand the need to put the patterns in non-capturing group '(?:\+A|0|1|-1|D|A|!D|!A|-D|-A)'